# Simplify exponential sum over $\mathbb{F}_p$ to prove identity

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, exponential-sum

I have a sum involving  $p$-th roots of unity (where $\frac{1}{t}$ is to be understood as the field inverse $t^{-1} \bmod p$ etc.) of the form

$\begin{align*}
&d_{j,k}=\sum_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{F}_p}\omega^{\frac{1}{12}(a^3-c^3)+(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{8})(a^2-c^2)+(\frac{b}{2}+b^2)(a-c)+kc-ja}\end{align*}$

where $\omega=\exp(2 \pi i/p)$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity and $p$ is a prime greater than 3.

With the aid of a computer, I can confirm the above expression obeys

$\begin{align*}d_{j,k\neq j}=p^2 \sum_{r  \in \mathbb{F}_p}\omega^r=0
\end{align*}$

I have checked this for $5\leq p \leq 17$ and am confident this holds for all prime $p>3$.

Question: 
How can I manipulate the expression for $d_{j,k}$ in order to see that all $d_{j,k\neq j}$ (with $j,k \in \mathbb{F}_p$) evaluate to zero?

Comment: where do the $p^2$ come from? if the result is $0$ and you checked it with a computer, i dont see a reason for writing $p^2$ there.

Comment: @supinf Using MMA I was able to find a symbolic expression of that form for all off-diagonal elements. I thought it might be helpful to include i.e. it may may give some intuition as to how to factorize the expression.

Comment: ok^^.
do you know if the exponent is (in general) an integer?
(could be interesting, if it is not the case, i suggest you to use a form where you have integers in the exponent (because $\omega$ is complex), i.e. use $\omega_1 = \omega^{\frac{1}{24}}$)

Comment: @supinf Edited to reflect that fractions are to be interpreted as field inverses, so that all exponents are integers.

Comment: ah ok thx, that makes an important difference! maybe use the term "field inverse" in your question too, $\frac{1}{t} = t^{-1} $ is not very informative for me

Comment: You never say what $\omega$ is. I guess it's a root of unity, but it's not clear what field it is in (the complex numbers? the field of $p$ elements? some extension of the field of $p$ elements?), nor what its order is (a $p$th root of unity? something else?).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Edited to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Mark, I'm a bit curious. Is the origin of this character sum a secret?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hi Jyrki, It's not a secret but would take a while to explain fully (I can provide more detail elsewhere if you like? - I work in quantum theory). Essentially $d_{j,k}$ are the matrix elements of a matrix $D$ which I believed to be diagonal. $D$ arises as $U^{-1} B U$ for a matrix $B$ whose eigenbasis I was interested in. $U$ is a unitary whose columns are of the form $\sum_k \omega^{f(k)} e_k$ where $e_k$ is the unit vector and $f$ is a cubic polynomial.

Comment: Sounds cool, Mark. I didn't know finite fields pop up in quantum theory like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character sum involves the polynomial
$$
f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}{12}(a^3-c^3)+(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{1}{8})(a^2-c^2)+(\frac{b}{2}+b^2)(a-c)+kc-ja.
$$
Staring at this for a while suggested to me to look at
$$
f(A+C,B-A/2-1/4,A-C)=\frac{C^3}6+C\left(-\frac18+2B^2-j-k\right)+A(-j+k)
$$
instead (ain't Mathematica's `Simplify` wonderful!).

In the interest of avoiding those tiny double supercripts let me define $e(x)=\omega^x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}_p$.

The linear substitution $(A,B,C)\mapsto (A+C,B-A/2-1/4,A-C)$ is bijective because $p>2$. Therefore we might as well use $(A,B,C)$ as summation variables and let them range over the entire field. We get
$$
\begin{aligned}
d_{j,k}&=\sum_{A,B,C\in\Bbb{F}_p}e\left(\frac{C^3}6+C\left(-\frac18+2B^2-j-k\right)+A(-j+k)\right)\\
&=\sum_{B,C\in\Bbb{F}_p}e\left(\frac{C^3}6+C\left(-\frac18+2B^2-j-k\right)\right)
\sum_{A\in\Bbb{F}_p}e(A[k-j]).
\end{aligned}
$$
Here I used the fact that $e(x+y)=e(x)e(y)$, which allowed us to take that $A$-sum as a common factor.

Anyway, if $k\neq j$, then the $A$-sum is trivially zero. Thus $d_{j,k}=0$ unless $k=j$.
The key to success was the ability to separate that simple $A$-sum.

Comment: Of course, when $k=j$ the $A$-sum is just $p$, and you can keep going, and simplify the sum further.

Comment: In my own efforts, I had gotten as far as trying $a=A+C$, $c=A-C$ and $b=B-\frac{1}{4}$ but then got stuck at that point. Thank you so much.

Comment: Mark, that's exactly how I started my pencil work. After realizing that further work is error prone I fired up Mathematica. Then I noticed that the terms linear in $C$ had a factor that looked like $2(B+A/2)^2$. The rest was easy. You were very close in solving it without any help.